# Boost, Eclipse and C++ I want to set this up

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I am currently working with Eclipse and the CDT. Admittedly, I am not an experienced C or C++ programmer. Apart from writing code and hitting "run!" I'm not too knowledgeable on how to build C++ code and consequently am running around google searches like a headless chicken trying to get the CDT to work with boost libraries. All guides are different (many are outdated) and nothing seems to work. I was hoping for some comprehensive help on how one would go about setting it up. In case this information is necessary: I will be working with boost threads in my assignments.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your working environment/target system?? Hard to give any advice without this information.

Comment: May be you should elaborate what particular problems you've been facing!

Answer (score 1):

In general the steps are as follows:

1. Install boost libraries on your working environment
2. Add include and library paths to your Eclipse CDT project properties (C++ Build)
3. Add the boost libs you need to your linker libraries (C++ Build properties also)

But this might have concrete obstacles and deviations to solve, depending on your specific target system. If it's the same as your working environment host system this is usually not a problem.

Comment: I'm working on a windows 7 64-bit machine using the latest version of Eclipse (Kepler), the latest version of MinGW GCC (4.7.2) and the latest version of boost (1.52).

Comment: @Galipan, latest version of boost is 1.54, BTW.